# Accessing external resources

Tags: java, android, eclipse, resources, themes

So I have an Android application that I'm coding multiple themes for (different background drawables for buttons and such).  I have everything packaged and working, but I'm finding that my resource folder is getting incredibly bulky.  So much so that it's foot print is triple the foot print of my source code directory.  I've done some searching around on google (and here) but can't find anything that seems to fit.  I've read the api docs and I'm coming up null there as well.  So here's what I'm looking for in a nutt-shell:

I'd like to make a few small packages that contain the resource files for use with this application.  By packaging the additional resource images separately I can dramatically reduce the size of my application.  How can you access an external resource file?  Is their a reliable way to tell whether one of these "theme packages" is installed on the device?  (i.e. if there isn't one, load the default.  If there is one, show it in the options.  If their are more than one theme packages installed, show them all.)

Answer (score 1):

A very easy solution would be to give the user the option to download additional themes straight to the external storage (mostly sd-card) if he would like to use them.

Just make your self a folder there and put your theme packages into it, then you simply have to check if there is something in the folder and give the options to the user, etc. etc.

Many famous Apps in the market are also doing it that way.

EDIT:

1: Ah I see. If you want to outsource theme files in other apk's you need to use the PackageManager. With it you can retrieve a list of all apps installed and for instance check if the packageName include a some string like ".someapp.superdupertheme" and than access the resources of the app with getResourcesForApplication. It's not as easy as with the external storage above and there are many more things to consider.

2: To avoid listing of your external files in the Android media gallery simply put a file named ".nomedia" in your folder and the Android media scanner will ignore it.

Comment: I've seen other apks that have themes on the market.  That's actually what I'm looking for.  So in my main application I would create a directory.  Then, when a theme apk is executed it would store it's resources in that folder in it's own sub directory.  My program would check to see if anythings in that directory, and if not go to default theme settings.  Thank you, that's what I'm looking for (can't believe I didn't think of that)  The last part of my question though, how do you iterate through the subdirectories and populate a list based on the directory names?

Comment: I just thought of one issue that I would likely have with this approach.  The .png files would show up in the user's gallery apk.  That is a huge no-go for me.  I hate a cluttered gallery.  So the other theme apks I've seen on the market have found a way around this.  It'd be awesome if someone out there would do a tutorial on handling this type of issue.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll look into PackageManager tonight to see if that's an avenue I want to go down.  This file named .nomedia, is it just a regular file with no extension?  i.e. to create it on my computer right click > new text document > ".nomedia" as file name with no extension (.txt)

Comment: Exactly, in Linux means a leading dot that the file should be hidden. If you create the file in Windows it's possible that it complains that there is no file name. Simply rename the file with the command prompt or create it directly in Android to avoid that.